# MapView add multiple markers through webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-mapview

I have a `MapView` and the markers are added to the map after a request to a webservice and after being parsed.

Right now, i have to wait to the request and the parsing and sometimes it takes a lot of time. So i would like to know if it is possible to add the markers to the map as they are being parsed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ItemizedOverlay`. You can add the different markers to this overlay as they come like so:

```
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}
```

Also see the [Maps tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview).

Comment: I know how to add the markers. But what i want to know is what is the best approach to add the markers as they are being parsed.Should i use a `AsyncTask` or `Thread`? And in case of multiple requests what is the best way to control when the all the requests are finished

Comment: AsyncTask would be better as its `onProgressUpdate()` method is executed in the UI-Thread, so that would be the place to add the markers to the overlay. So you'd make your requests in `doInBackground()` and when parsing the response, for every marker you call `publishProgress()` with infos about the marker and in `onProgressUpdate()` you add them to the overlay.